# Solving Probability Given Expected Value

Tags: probability, integration

I am given the following equations

$$\int_0^{S_1} P(x) \, dx + \int_{S_1}^{S_2} P(x) \, dx + \int_{S_2}^\infty P(x) \, dx = 1$$
$$\alpha\int_0^{S_1} P(x) \, dx + \int_{S_1}^{S_2} (x - \gamma)P(x) \, dx + \beta\int_{S_2}^\infty P(x) \, dx = 0$$

where $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, and $S_1$, $S_2$ are all constant, known values, and $P(X)$ is the probability density function for a random variable.

I know the value of $\int_0^{S_1} P(x) \, dx$, and am specificially interested in solving for the value of $\int_{S_1}^{S_2} P(x) \, dx$. Is it possible given this system of equations? I'm having trouble solving for $\int_{S_1}^{S_2} P(x) \, dx$ but I feel like there is some way to at least estimate the value?

Comment: you have like 5 variables and 2 equations

Comment: Isn't the only variable the $x$ in the middle of the second integral, and $P(X)$?

Comment: do you know the values of alpha, beta, and gamma?

Comment: Yes, and the values of $S_1$ and $S_2$, they are all constants with known values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know the value of $\int^{S_1}_0P(x)dx$, and am specificially interested in solving for the value of $\int^{S_2}_{S_1}P(x)dx$. Is it possible given this system of equations?

No. If you cannot find $\int^{S_2}_{S_1}P(x)dx$ from the first equation, then you also do not know $\int^{\infty}_{S_2}P(x)dx$.   Further, if you do not know $P$ well enough to evaluate $\int^{S_2}_{S_1}P(x)dx$ you likely do not know it well enough to evaluate $\int^{S_2}_{S_1}xP(x)dx$.

If that is true, then you have two simultaneous equations with three unknowns.

---

Let $A=\int^{S_1}_{S_0}P(x)dx$, $X=\int^{S_2}_{S_1}P(x)dx$, $Y=\int^{\infty}_{S_2}P(x)dx$, $Z=\int^{S_2}_{S_1}xP(x)dx$, then your equations are$$\begin{align}A+X+Y&=1\\\alpha A+Z-\gamma X+\beta Y&=0\end{align}$$

Comment: Is there any way to use linear approximation to estimate the value of the integral without explicitly solving for it?

Comment: Do you have any information on the probability measure?